# Restful APIs: readonly / writeonly fields

Tags: rest

I have a conceptual question with restful apis. In my data model, I have countries and companies.

Users of the api won't be able to create country objects. There are constant entries in the database for countries. They will be creating company objects, which have country as a field. So when creating a company, api expects a json like:

```
{
    'name': 'company name',
    'country': 5, // country id
    ...
}
```

On the client side, when displaying a company, we also want to display its country. One approach to this is, after getting a company resource, we issue another get request to get the country object. But this approach is problematic performance-wise, especially on the pages we list multiple companies.

Another approach would be to include country details in another field on get requests, like:

```
{
    'name': 'company name',
    'country': 5, // country id
    'country_details': {
        'name': 'USA',
        'phone_code': 1,
        'id': 5
    }
    ...
}
```

I do not think that this is the correct approach either, as data representation is different for post and get requests for the same resource. Have any suggestions for this case?

Answer (score 1):

> ...as data representation is different for post and get requests for the same resource.

`POST` from [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3):

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request...

Whereas `PUT`:

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
> created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload.  A successful PUT of a given
> representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same
> target resource will result in an equivalent representation being
> sent in a 200 (OK) response.

And:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT methods is
> highlighted by the different intent for the enclosed representation.
> The target resource in a POST request is intended to handle the
> enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantics,
> whereas the enclosed representation in a PUT request is defined as
> replacing the state of the target resource.

So `POST` and `GET` bodies differing is not a problem, but it would be for `PUT` and `GET`. I would make the distinction clearer by not using the same URL for `POST` and `GET`. Which makes sense anyway as the `GET` would include a company identifier, whereas the `POST` won't.

For example, maybe it makes sense for companies to be posted to a country URL, this way we don't need to include the country id in the body:

```
POST: /usa/company

BODY: { 'name': 'company name' }

RESPONSE: 200 with Content-Location header: /companies/1
```

Then the subsequent `GET` of that `Content-Location`:

```
GET: /companies/1

RESPONSE: { 'name': 'company name', 'country': 'USA' }
```